# Javascript classes in ES6, how to import them within other js-files and in html files?

Tags: javascript, html, class, oop, ecmascript-6

Obviously, I am a beginner and trying to figure out basic staff, so please bear with me!

I have all these files (index.html, app.js and calc.js) in the same folder and their content is shown below.

I have 2 issues:

**1:** why in file (app.js), importing class *Calc* and creating a new instance of it works, whereas in file (calc.js) similar process doesn't work with class *Test*?

**2:** how could I use the class "Calc" for example in the *.html file?

Note: I am using chrome (62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)) on mac OS 10.13

```
// app.js
import { Calc } from './calc.js';

class Test {
    static hello() {
        console.log("hello from class1");
    }
}

let c = new Calc(); // this works!

console.log(c.sum(2, 3) + 1); // 6

export { Test };
```

and

```
// calc.js
import { Test } from "./app.js";

class Calc {
    sum(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

let t = new Test(); // Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined
t.hello();

export { Calc };
```

Finally the HTML file:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="./app.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="./calc.js" type="module"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>ES6</h1>
<script>
    let c = new Calc();
    // simulate input summation from two textboxes for example
    console.log(c.sum(2, 1)); //Uncaught ReferenceError: Calc is not defined
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Problem 1:**

You have a circular dependency - `app.js` imports `calc.js`, but `calc.js` imports `app.js`.

Usually the module system will ensure all of a module's dependencies are executed before the module itself, but this is impossible when your dependency tree has cycles - it *has* to pick one of them to run first. In this case, `calc.js` is run first, at which point `Test` isn't yet defined!

There are ways to work around this if you're careful, but cyclic dependencies are pretty much always a sign that you're structuring your code wrong - the best solution is to reorganize it so you no longer have a cycle.

**Problem 2:**

ES2016 modules don't execute in the global scope. If you want to make something available to the window as a whole, you need to be explicit:

```
window.Calc = Calc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. **Problem1** was *solved perfectly*. However in **Problem2** i still get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: Calc is not defined` in spite of that I added the script in the header `<script src="./calc.js" type="module"></script>`. In other words, I cannot add the property `window.Calc`, since the class Calc is not defined!

Comment: Where are you putting the `window.Calc = Calc`? It needs to be in one of your modules, not in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you :) this has solved the remaining problem :D

Comment: @user2804070: Brilliant :) I'd recommend keeping all of your code in the modules rather than having some of it in the HTML if you can, because it makes things a lot cleaner - sometimes you don't have a choice though, so it's good to know how to work around it.